# JavaScript Unknown Error in Code

Tags: javascript, html

So Im making a simple guessing game and the numbers go from 1-10. The issue is whenever I guess the number right it still says that I get it wrong here is the source code for the program. (Is that the proper meaning of source code?)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>First Proper HTML page</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <p>This is my first website</p>
    <p>Its very fun and exciting</p>
    <p><a href="http://xkcd.com" title="xkcd:Land of geeky comics!">Click here </a>
    <script>
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random(100) * 11);
    //console.log(randomNumber);
    var guess = prompt("Please guess a number 1 - 10");
    if(guess === randomNumber){
    alert("You have won! The number was " + randomNumber);
    }else{
    alert("You have guessed the wrong number, the real number was  " +              randomNumber);
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `guess === randomNumber` here you are doing is strict checking. the type of randonNumber is number and guess is string. In strict checking mode data type won't convert. Try like this `guess == randomNumber`

Comment: Change guess === randomNumber to only use == instead of ===.  Also, make sure the types are matching.  The input is probably coming in as a string but your comparing it to an integer.  Put a parseInt around the guess so they are both integer types.

Comment: Remember to name questions more accurate

Answer (score 3):

You are using strict comparison (===), this will evaluate that the value and the type are equal, I believe you should use `parseInt` in `guess` as follows:

```
if(parseInt(guess) === randomNumber){
```

Answer (score 1):

This does a strict comparison:

```
if(guess === randomNumber)
```

It returns false if the variables are not of the same type.

In your code, `guess` is a string, because it's the result of the `prompt()`.  `randomNumber` is a number.  Since a string and a number are not the same type, it will always return false.

You can fix this by changing the `if` condition to:

```
if(guess == randomNumber)
```

This will cause JavaScript to coerce `guess` to a number.

Alternatively, you could force the coercion by using `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()`, or by simply prepending a plus sign to `guess`:

```
if(+guess === randomNumber)
```

Comment: I don't know why it got downvoted.  It seems like a reasonable question.  There's been a lot of downvoting going on recently.

Answer (score 1):

Change ===  to ==.  It should help. The number from the prompt is a string so you can't compare with triple equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

(===) is used for equal types of variables, such as

```
true
```

and

```
false
```

The solution is, you need to use (==) which states if the variable is equal to another variable

Answer (score 0):

When you code please pay attention to your indentation, it helps a lot when you or others might read the code.

Anyway, this should do it, what you did wrong was basically the way you were calling the random function.

Also the == operator should be enough as you are just comparing values, === means equal value and equal type.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

console.log(randomNumber);

var guess = prompt("Please guess a number 1 - 10");

if(guess == randomNumber){
    alert("You have won! The number was " + randomNumber);
}else{
    alert("You have guessed the wrong number, the real number was  " + randomNumber);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dxpme8zo/